# How to clean up json string from Request.Url

Tags: c#, json

I'm looking for a way to clean up the following json string in C# to be more usable.

"?{\"token\":\"I3dt-MIByyWD5-XqF6VT3hQSk8qvy9r6\"}"

basically just for a way to strip it down to

"token:I3dt-MIByyWD5-XqF6VT3hQSk8qvy9r6" or just "I3dt-MIByyWD5-XqF6VT3hQSk8qvy9r6"

I assume that a  would be good for accomplishing this but unfortunately i've never written one before and a bit lost on how to get what im looking for using one. The parsing is happening in C# BTW.

**EDIT**: Correction a regular expression probably wont do what i want... i want to format the string.. not just validate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to parse it into a `JSON` object, then using the `JSON` API, to get the value of the `token` key from there.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx

there is a class, called JsonTextReader, which you can use for parsing.
Here's how:

```
string jsonText = @"[""Europe"", ""Asia"", ""Australia"", ""Antarctica"",
 ""North America"", ""South America"", ""Africa""]";

using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new
 StringReader(jsonText)))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.TokenClass == JsonTokenClass.String &&
            reader.Text.StartsWith("A"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try a method like this. the & take it for separator if you have a chain of such `"?{\"token\":\"I3dt-MIByyWD5-XqF6VT3hQSk8qvy9r6\"&\"other\":\"123\"}"`. Also clears the characters "and \

```
static string MyParserJson(string sjson, string key)
{
    try
    {
        if (!(sjson.Contains("{") && sjson.Contains("}")))
            throw new ApplicationException("don't exist { or }");

        int inipos = sjson.IndexOf("{");
        int endpos = sjson.IndexOf("}");

        var myjson = sjson.Substring(inipos + "{".Length, endpos - (inipos + "{".Length));
        string[] ajson = myjson.Split('&');

        foreach (var keyval in ajson)
        {
            if (!keyval.Contains(":"))
                continue;

            string[] afind = keyval.Split(':');

            if (afind[0].Contains(key))
            {
                return afind[1].Replace("\"", "").Replace("\\", "").Trim();
            }
        }

    }
    catch
    {
          //test
    }

    return string.Empty;
}


var uri = "?{\"token\":\"I3dt-MIByyWD5-XqF6VT3hQSk8qvy9r6\"}";
var token = MyParserJson(uri, "token");
```